# How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP 7.2.11

Tags: php, arrays

I found the following code on the internet, but it does not work as it should on Windows 10 with Laragon and PHP 7.2.11.

```
  $myMultiArray = [
    ['Php','Laravel'],
    ['Html','Css'],
    ['Php','Laravel'],   ];

$uniqueMyArray =  array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $myMultiArray)));

echo "<pre>"; print_r($myMultiArray); echo "</pre>";
```

It outputs the following, so it does not filter the array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Php
            [1] => Laravel
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Html
            [1] => Css
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Php
            [1] => Laravel
        )

)
```

Can anyone relate to this?

Comment: `it does not work as it should on Windows 10`...does it work correctly on a different platform then? That's what you seem to be implying? What have you tested? As far as I can see there is nothing O/S-specific in your code. It's irrelevant.

Comment: I doubt this demo site runs on Windows and the result is the same: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9921c9bbeaf651c42f1eacea2313a719e97ecd2a . So yeah, nothing to do with Windows, or Laragon for that matter.

Comment: Anyway the actual problem is you're just outputting the wrong variable at the end - you're looking at the original data, not the filtered data...please pay closer attention and always double-check your work. it works fine if you look at the correct data:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e47864442feb6bf706ef34034625586e5afbe87 . Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I've been trying to find this error for hours now....

Comment: It happens to us all sometimes. https://rubberduckdebugging.com/ might be a good technique to help you in this kind of situation. It sounds a bit silly but it's quite effective - it forces you to go back through your code and examine every detail, and check whether it really does what you've been assuming it does. Hopefully in that process you'd then look closely at the `echo` line and see that it outputs the wrong variable.